# jQuery adding to current margin-left value

Tags: jquery, onclick, slider

I have two div buttons, 'slide-forward' and 'slide-back'. They need to control the value of margin-left on my div '.inner'. Each time one of the buttons is clicked, it needs to subtract or add 100% to the current margin-left of 'inner'.

Suppose the current margin-left value of '.inner' is set at -300%.
On click of 'slide-forward' the result would be margin-left -200%.
Then on click of 'slide-backward' the result would be margin-left -300%.
If user clicks on 'slide-backward' again, result would be margin-left -400%.

So essentially, on click my buttons, my div's margin-left would add or subtract incrementally. It's vital that the value is in % not px.

I apologize if this is hard to understand. It's a bit hard to explain. If you don't understand what I'm trying to do please say so and I will break it down further.

My code (doesn't quite  work):

```
$('.slide-back').data('marginLeft', '0').on('click',function(){
    var $inner = $('.inner'),
        curMarg = $(this).data('marginLeft') + 100;

    $inner.css({marginLeft:curMarg+'%'});
    $(this).data('marginLeft',curMarg);
});

$('.slide-forward').data('marginLeft', '0').on('click',function(){
    var $inner = $('.inner'),
        curMarg = $(this).data('marginLeft') - 100;

    $inner.css({marginLeft:curMarg+'%'});
    $(this).data('marginLeft',curMarg);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery .data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) set a variable into a DOM element. In your code, you are setting 2 different var on 2 elements. That mean you are not adding or substracting on the same value.

In this case, if you have only 1 `.inner`, you don't really need to use `.data()`, a simple var should work :

```
var marginCalc = 0;

$('.slide-back').on('click',function(){
    var $inner = $('.inner');

    marginCalc += 100;

    $inner.css({marginLeft:marginCalc+'%'});
});

$('.slide-forward').on('click',function(){
    var $inner = $('.inner');

    marginCalc -= 100;

    $inner.css({marginLeft:marginCalc+'%'});
});
```

If you want to keep the `.data()` way, you should have the data to `.inner` div :

```
$('.inner').data('marginLeft', 0);

$('.slide-back').on('click',function(){
    var $inner = $('.inner'),
        nextMLeft = $('.inner').data('marginLeft');

    nextMLeft += 100;

    $inner.css({marginLeft:nextMLeft+'%'});
});

$('.slide-forward').on('click',function(){
    var $inner = $('.inner'),
        nextMLeft = $('.inner').data('marginLeft');

    nextMLeft -= 100;

    $inner.css({marginLeft:nextMLeft+'%'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I used your first solution. Do you know if its friendly all major browsers? I'm new to jQuery so I don't know much. But I'm def eager to learn!

Comment: It is pretty basic JS so i think it is compatible with every major browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you should keep the data on the element you are moving, not on the slide-forward / slide-backward buttons.

Here is a fiddle of a working version of what you asked for:

http://jsfiddle.net/ySnrb/

```
var $box = $('.box');

var percentToMove = 20; // would be 100 for your example, but just to keep things on screen for this answer make it 20
$('#forward').on('click', function() {
    var left = $box.data('left');
    $box.css('margin-left', (left + percentToMove) + '%');
    $box.data('left', left + percentToMove);
});

$('#back').on('click', function() {
    var left = $box.data('left');
    $box.css('margin-left', (left - percentToMove) + '%');
    $box.data('left', left - percentToMove);
});
```